# Change color link from one wordpress menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to know how I can change the color from my menu. I would like to change just one link. Gewerbekunden. The other one should be white and the gewerbekunden link should be have a other color but i dont know how. the styles that I give them don't work. [my site](http://sweety-toys.de/)

```
.dark-header #masthead ul.header-nav a.nav-top-link,:opacity:1.7
```

That is the css for the navi, if I put a color:red into it is everything red but i just want gewerbekunden red.

Comment: can we get the HTML part of your code

Comment: @user3662624 Just saw your Scroll problem q..what happend was able to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you've added a class called "image-column2" to this menu item. What you could do then is add this to your stylesheet:

```
.dark-header #masthead ul.header-nav .image-column2 a.nav-top-link { color:red; }
```

You can also use the ID of the menu item to target it, but that's not recommendable.

The best solution would be to use a modular class like .font-red on the  tag. However, since there are several nested rules, you cannot use `.font-red { color:red; }` since it will be overwritten, so you have to use either `.font-red { color:red !important; }` or `.dark-header #masthead ul.header-nav .image-column2 a.nav-top-link.font-red { color:red; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much you know:
Create another class in your CSS which color:red
Something similar to .dark-header

> .red-link {
>   color:red
>   }

and apply it to your link.

```
 <a href class=red-link>Gewerbekunden</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following class in your css

```
 .dark-header #masthead ul.header-nav li:nth-child(5) a {color:red}
```